# Saving RecyclerView list State

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onsaveinstancestate, onrestoreinstancestate

I have a recyclerView containing list of a objects of a class. Currently when I close my app all the list in the recyclerView gets lost and after restarting the app, recyclerView shows nothing(no list).

What and How shall I use to retain the list even after my is closed and destroyed?

```
public class Info  {
public String pName;
public String pContact;
public Character pGender;
public int pID;
public String tDateTime;   // today's date and time
}
```

I am storing objects of this class in arraylist to populate my recyclerview adapter.

Comment: you can use local  database to store data follo this link http://www.androidauthority.com/how-to-store-data-locally-in-android-app-717190/

Comment: What data you show on your list? Could you share your source?

Comment: how you fill data? I need that source, anyway. If you fill your data manually, entering by EditText's, then you should use sqlite database.

Comment: Added class info above is shown in the list.

Comment: Yes, I fill data by Edittext

Comment: Is there a way to retain these list views using onSaveInstanceState without using database?

Answer (score 1):

Save state:

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle state) {
     super.onSaveInstanceState(state);

     // Save list state
     mListState = mLayoutManager.onSaveInstanceState();
     state.putParcelable(LIST_STATE_KEY, mListState);
}
```

Restore state :

```
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle state) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);

    // Retrieve list state and list/item positions
    if(state != null)
        mListState = state.getParcelable(LIST_STATE_KEY);
}
```

Then update the LayoutManager :

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (mListState != null) {
        mLayoutManager.onRestoreInstanceState(mListState);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work. RecyclerView still remains empty after closing of app.

Answer (score 1):

Override onSaveInstanceState in the activity and save the state of your model, not the state of your layout manager. You surely have the data model somewhere, if the view shows any data at all.

As very minimum, you need to remember just the number of items currently in the model. This is if the model is capable of fetching the content of required items from somewhere. If it is not, or takes too long, the state needs to include also the items being displayed. Something like

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
  super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
  outState.putSerializable("d.list.data", adapter.getState());
}
```

And, where state must be restored:

```
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
  adapter.setState(savedInstanceState.getSerializable("d.list.data"));
}
```

[Here](https://github.com/andviane/google-books-android-viewer/blob/master/uncover/src/main/java/com/ames/uncover/UncoveringDataModel.java) is the code of the class that saves and applies state for the model used with the RecyclerView.

Comment: Llink is break :(

Comment: Link should now be fixed. Thanks for reporting.